# Javascript, array manipulation using reduce and map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to re-compartmentalize an array.

So take this array [col1,col2,col3,col4]

and I need to nest the array - so the first element is on its own like this

[[col1], [col2,col3,col4]]

I've tried the following code -- but its then pushing col2 into the first array position

jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/57 - what my example is doing

```
k['key'] = i
if (i % 2 === 0) {
 m.push([k])
} else {
 m[m.length - 1].push(k)
}
return m
```

My effort:

```js
function arrayMaker(menu) {
  var l = []
  menu.reduce((m, k, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      m.push([k])
    } else {
      l.push(k)
    }
    if (i === menu.length - 1) {
      m.push(l)
    }
    console.log("m", m)
    return m
  }, [])

}

var menu = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
var nest = arrayMaker(menu)
console.log("nest", nest)
```

---

alright guys - this is the full bulk of the code - why it looks so complicated for something so simple.

```
    {
     lang.menu.reduce((m, k, i) => {
       m.push(k)
       if (i === lang.menu.length - 1) {
         m = [m.slice(0, 1), m.slice(1)]
       }
       return m
     }, []).map((grouped, index) => (
       <div key={index} className={index === 0 ? 'main-footer__left' : 'main-footer__right'}>
         {
           <div className='row grid__row--offset--30'>
             {
               grouped.map((item, j) =>
                 <div key={j} className={(index === 0 && j === 0 ? 'large-45 large-centered' : 'large-14 large-offset-5') + ' columns'}>
                   <h2 className='text--uppercase text--white footer-text'>{item.title}</h2>
                   {
                     item.switch
                       ? <p className='text--white grid__row--offset--15 footer-text'>
                         {
                           item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                             return (
                               <Link key={j} className={'text--white footer-text transition ' + (props.active_language === child.title.toString().toLowerCase() ? activeLang : alternativeLang)} to={urls[j]}>{child.title}</Link>
                             )
                           })
                         }
                       </p>
                       : item.children.map(function (child, j) {
                         return (
                           <div key={j} className={(j === 0 ? ' grid__row--offset--15' : '')}>
                             <Link className='text--white footer-text transition' to={child.link}>{child.title}</Link>
                           </div>
                         )
                       })
                   }
                 </div>
               )
             }
           </div>
         }
       </div>
      ))
    }
```

Comment: please add the real object/s

Comment: Better: Click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: This seems like a deferred question. What's the real problem you're trying to address here?

Comment: I've just explained the issue. you have 1 array -- need to nest it inside another, but have the first element placed in the first part

Comment: `k=[[arr.slice(0,1)],[arr.slice(1)]]` or something (I'm very tired) - but create a full example with expected output before you get voted to hell and the question closed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/57/ - what my example is doing

Comment: @mplungjan, too much brackets.

Comment: `i % 2` makes no sense based on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @charlietfl -- yes I know - inside the reduce - what's the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with the array for a new array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = [array.slice(0, 1), array.slice(1)];
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: m.push(k)
               if (i === lang.menu.length - 1) {
                 m = [m.slice(0, 1), m.slice(1)]
               }
               return m

Answer (score 2):

I like to cheat:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4],
   result = [[array.shift()], array];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But that doesn't seem to work?  If your question is accurate the above code or any of the other answers should do it for ya.

Comment: well its in the reducer

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4];
var result=arr.reduce((a,e,i)=>((a[i?1:0]=a[i?1:0]||[]).push(e),a),[]);
```